# How to calculate mining profits in Excel?

Tags: mining-profitability

I am aware that tools such as [this one](https://www.cryptocompare.com/mining/calculator/xmr) and [this one](http://www.coinwarz.com/calculators/monero-mining-calculator) exist to calculate estimated mining profits. I would like to essentially recreate these in Excel (with perhaps a few additional features).

Fileds to use: Hash rate, power, power cost, difficulty, block reward,
pool rejects, pool fees, XMR/fiat, and hardware costs.

Ideally, I would then use this information to estimate mining profits in the future (6 months, 1 year, 2 years, 3 years, etc) using the reward curve and projecting a difficulty over time. It would also be cool to mess around with the price of Monero over time, for example assuming the price will increase 5% a month on average or something like that. I want to be able to manipulate the variables to compare profit possibilities.

Does anyone have any thoughts of how to do this? I can make an Excel document, but I do not know what calculations to put into Excel.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this in a couple parts:

1.) First of all review how you would integrate an API feed into Excel:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NX4Jb3Tj3J4 or
- https://www.import.io/post/how-to-get-live-web-data-into-a-spreadsheet-without-ever-leaving-excel/
- or even something like Alteryx

2.) You'll need access to a real-time API that has the current traded value of the currency.

- https://poloniex.com/support/api/

3.) Finally you'll just need to calculate the the hash rate to XMR conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Specific to Monero, I came across this Google Sheets based solution you may find as an alternate or base for ideas.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OiUss7aVoz7dndx4qVFMA9Hm0BECaSBh-jWccNYnD2k/edit?usp=sharing